# Geo shard key + Cosmos DB

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, geojson, sharding, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

I try to create a collection in CosmosDB and I don't know how to create a good shardkey !

I had something like that in mind, but it does not accept my shard-key !

```
{
"shard_key" : ["50.836421", "4.355267"],
"position":
  {
    "type": "Point",
    "coordinates": [50.836421, 4.355267]
  },
}
```

Does someone has experience with this?

Answer (score 1):

You could make the `shard_key`  as `"[\"50.836421\", \"4.355267\"]"`,it is accepted by cosmos db mongo api.

Based on the [book](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920028031.do) and the [link](https://books.google.com.sg/books?id=pAbSHFi4WSAC&pg=PT367&lpg=PT367&dq=mongodb%20shard%20key%20array&source=bl&ots=Dv2hKzn5q6&sig=u89Y1WyxzDayfrq9N3uHhutfhTQ&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiB09fo95HdAhVBNI8KHfjpBAM4FBDoATABegQICRAB#v=onepage&q=mongodb%20shard%20key%20array&f=false), shard-key from array is not supported by mongo db.

> Shard keys cannot be arrays. sh.shardCollection() will fail if any key
>   has an array value and inserting an array into that field is not
>   allowed. Once inserted, a document's shard key value cannot be
>   modified. To change a document's shard key, you must remove the
>   document, change the key, and reinsert it. Thus, you should choose a
>   field that is unchangeable or changes frequently.

Hope it helps you.

Comment: Thanks a lot, but I use CosmosDB with SQL API... it seems that it does not work. When I try to insret a document, I got an error message :-(

Comment: @Krysalid What error you got? You mean partition key in cosmos db sql api?

Comment: Sorry, it work, I didn't put the quete around. But then it is just a string ? not a compound field ? It will be the same to use "50.836421_4.355267" by example then ? Thx

Comment: but this is not a solution, a string hash will not be indexed like a geo-location. It is a hack but it is an incorrect way to partition the datas !

Comment: @Krysalid So, I'm confused. You do want to make the partition key as geo-location array,right?? However ,it is can't be done so far.

Comment: the partitioning must organize the data based on their geographical proximity, by example all the US data have to be together, all the EU data together... basically it is the idea. A string with concatenated Latitude+Longitude will not provide such behavior ;-)

Comment: @Krysalid Hi,could you maybe consider storing the extra area field as partition key by the latitude and longitude.